# Google Maps v3 infoWindow addDomListener for HTML Button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a simple google Maps example 
JS File:

```
    /*Standard Setup Google Map*/ 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922); 
    var myOptions = { 
        zoom: 15, 
        center: latlng, 
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };

    // add Map 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    // add Marker
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922)
    });

    // add Info Window
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Now i want to open the info Box when i click on a button in the my html template:

HTML File:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
 ...
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 ...
 <button id="test">Click</button>
 ...
</body>
```

adding these lines to my JS File:

```
    var onMarkerHTMLClick = function() {

        var marker = this;
        var latLng = marker.getPosition();
        var content = '<div style="text-align: center; font-size:14px;"><center><b>Company GmbH</b></center><div>Broadway Str.5</div><div>45132 Canvas</div></div>';

        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(15);

        infoWindow.setContent(content);

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
     };

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("test"),'click', onMarkerHTMLClick);
```

error: marker.getPosition is not a function
why should this not work? If i do the same with a click function on the marker itself the window opens with no problems..

Comment: Button is not a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the event that opens the infoWindow. Probably the easiest thing to do is store your markers in a global array or if you dont have many just select them by ID.

**Example**

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('THE_ID');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(myButton, 'click', openInfoWindow);
```

**openInfoWindow** just being the callback function where you can trigger the event.

Comment: ah ok this should work and i have to set var marker = marker1; instead of var marker = this;